# DoEvents not giving control to Windows in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make an autosave function in Excel as the current Microsoft one does not word for local file.

Here is the VB I have come up with. But still only macro is running, not giving Windows any control. The `DoEvents` seems not to work.

```
Sub Auto_save()   
    Do While 1 < 2    
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
        DoEvents
    Loop

End Sub
```

(I'm using Excel 365 Pro Plus.)

Comment: You got a never ending loop in there?

Comment: @QHarr, looks that way, but logical if you want to build your own autosave function...

Comment: @Luuklag I believe you but why?

Comment: @Qharr beats me... Perhaps a worksheet change event could do the trick, checking current time against `lastsavetime` and if the difference is larger then X go save.

Comment: VBA will keep control after `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))` for 5 secs and before you know rest of the code for `Do..Loop` will be over! If you want to build Auto_Save then you can use code samples posted for digital clocks in excel etc. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867225/how-do-i-show-a-running-clock-in-excel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking VBA to wait 5s which will freeze Excel during this time, and only after the `Wait` is finished, the `DoEvents` fires.

One solution that is often seen is to implement an own `wait`-function, using a loop containing a `DoEvents`, for example suggested at https://stackoverflow.com/a/21405463/7599798 (copied from there)

```
Private Sub delay(seconds As Long)
    Dim endTime As Date
    endTime = DateAdd("s", seconds, Now())
    Do While Now() < endTime
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

However, I think this not really a good solution because it keeps your CPU busy. An alternative is to use the `OnTime` function:

```
Sub SaveMe()
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "SaveMe"
End Sub
```

*Side note*: You shouldn't use `ActiveWorkbook`, because the focus could easily change to a different workbook and in that case you wouldn't save the workbook you are expecting.

Comment: Q: If I'm reading the code correctly, the `SaveMe` Sub is recursive. I have had a few (very few, thankfully) instances where using a recursive function built up the call stack too high, and it crashed. Does saving the workbook help clear the call stack? Or could there be a potential issue if a workbook with this code was left open too long?

Comment: @FunThomas `ThisWorkbook.Save`  instead of `ActiveWorkbook`

Comment: @BND: Not necessarily - depends if the code is within the workbook the OP wants to autosave.

Comment: @Mistella: Yes and no. The Sub is calling itself "in the future", but doesn't wait until then, so the stack doesn't increase.

Comment: Is it possible to integrate a macro to the excel program itself?
So that any thime you open a new excel file you macro is automatically run

Comment: @BND: You could add this to your `personal` workbook and run it all few minutes, looping thru all open workbooks. However, keep in mind that if you autosave all open files, you cannot close without saving - and personally, I have too often screwed up a file and was happy to quit and restart. Maybe using `SaveCopyAs` could be a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `DoEvents`. Example code copied and edited from [How do I show a running clock in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867225/how-do-i-show-a-running-clock-in-excel)

```
Dim TimerActive As Boolean
Sub StartTimer()
    Start_Timer
End Sub
Private Sub Start_Timer()
    TimerActive = True
    Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "Timer"
End Sub
Private Sub Stop_Timer()
    TimerActive = False
End Sub
Private Sub Timer()
    If TimerActive Then
        ThisWorkbook.Save
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = "Last saved by : " & Application.UserName & " on " & Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yy hh:mm:ss")
        Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "Timer"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please note that this solution requires the use of cells A1 on worksheet 1.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Excel 365/2016, TWO consecutive DoEvents commands are needed in the VBA code for a dynamic plot to update.  Strange but true.  Works every time.